# notation for union/intersection of set family

Tags: notation

Let $\mathcal{A}=\left\{A_1,A_2, \dots \right\} $ be a set family, i.e. $ A_1, A_2, \dots $ are sets.

Is  $ \bigcup \mathcal{A}=\bigcup \left\{A_1,A_2, \dots \right\} :=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ a standard notation? So $\bigcup \mathcal{A}$ would mean the union of sets in $\mathcal{A}$?

And the same for an intersection:
$ \bigcap \mathcal{A}=\bigcap \left\{A_1,A_2, \dots \right\} :=\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$

Comment: I have seen that notation in some of my courses. I think it is better to use it when you don't know whether the family is countable though.

Comment: Your notation is fine (regardless of what you know about the size of the index set, *pace* @GiorgosGiapitzakis).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a notation used occasionally, for example in ZF set theory.